# Let $G$ a finite group and $H\leq G$, such that $|H| = \frac{|G|}{2}$. If $x \in G$ then $x^2 \in H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ a finite group and $H\leq G$, such that $|H| =  \frac{|G|}{2}$.   If $x \in G$ then $x^2 \in H$

**My attempt:**

As $x \in G$ then $\operatorname{ord}(x)$ divide $|G|$ this implies that $|G| = k\cdot \operatorname{ord}(x)$ with $k\in \mathbb{N}$

Moreover, we know that

$$\operatorname{ord}(x^2)=\frac{\operatorname{ord}(x)}{\gcd(2,\operatorname{ord}(g))}$$

Then:

$$\operatorname{ord}(x^2)=\frac{|G|}{k\cdot \gcd(2,\operatorname{ord}(g))}$$

Here I'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2735454/if-h-le-g-and-h-has-index-2-in-g-then-a2-in-h-forall-a-in-g?noredirect=1&lq=1). The hint was: If $x^2H = xH$, then $xH = H$.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. But i don't see why $x^2H = xH$ can you give me a hint of this? @DietrichBurde

Comment: Use that the index is $2$, i.e, we have only two cosets.

Comment: ok thanks!!!!@DietrichBurde

Comment: If $[G:H]=2$, than $H\unlhd G$ and $G/H\cong C_2$. Therefore, for $a\in G\setminus H$, $aH$ has order $2$ in the quotient, *i.e.* $(aH)^2=a^2H=H$, whence $a^2\in H$. If $a\in H$, $a^2\in H$ by closure. Therefore, $a^2\in H$ for every $a\in G$.